# Simple_form text boxes are extremely long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form

[image: long inputs]

Using simple_form and bootstrap, and I'm having trouble getting the input boxes to size correctly. They're different, overly long, lengths. I can hardcode them in the CSS, but then they're non-responsive. (I tried max-width, but they end up a fixed width.) Also using the devise gem for user authentication.

Page Code:

```
<div class="booyah-box col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @validatable) %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Comment: please paste the code here.

Comment: You might want to use Google Chrome's Development tool to see what CSS rule is being applied to the text boxes. It looks like your CSS is broken somewhere.

Comment: Code pasted above. There's no specific CSS outside of the standard bootstrap/simple_form on those inputs at the moment. I had run into an issue where I'd generated the devise views before adding the simple_form gem, so I had to go back and re-generate the devise views afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, thats actually not true. Here's the CSS for the "booyah-box" class that the code sits in:

`.booyah-box {
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 #d0d0d0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 #d0d0d0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0 #d0d0d0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-color: #e4e4e4 #bebebd #bebebd #e4e4e4;
  padding:10px;
}

.booyah-box h2, .booyah-box h1 {
  margin:10px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
<h2>Sign up</h2>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>

   // you can add class **col-lg-6** in any input field for maintaining the width

    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @validatable), class: "form-control" %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign in", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Emu. Turns out a server restart fixed the issues.